# why php headers are getting huge time to redirect?

Tags: php

Im developping a very simple script with php and mysql. the problem is php header redirect getting huge time to redirect. without redirect script working very fast. Im using php header redirect for remove cashed form data and redirect process.php to root index..

### here is my index.php code...

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>myWall ~ V.02</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<?php
// import connect.php file.
require 'connect.php';
require 'form.php';

// checking form set || not && form empty || not.
if (isset($_POST['status'])){
    if (!empty($_POST['status'])){

        $status = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['status']));
        // sql query string for insert a status to database.
        $insertAStatus = "INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`id`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '".$status."');";
        mysqli_query($con,$insertAStatus);
        //echo 'added a status';

        // redirecting to main root for clear form submitted data.
        header('location: ../mywall');

    } else {

        echo 'Please enter a status.<br>';

    }
} // end. if isset.

// getting number of rows in db.
$getNumRows = "SELECT * FROM `status`;";
$gotNumRows = mysqli_query($con,$getNumRows);
$numOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($gotNumRows);
if ($numOfRows != 0){
echo 'You have '.$numOfRows.' Status.';
} else {
return NULL;
}


// display data in database.
$getData = "SELECT * FROM `status` ORDER BY `status`.`id` DESC";
$dataFromDb = mysqli_query($con,$getData);


// display data through while loop.
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dataFromDb,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo "<div style='padding: 5px; background:#F1F1F1; margin: 5px;'>".$row['status']."<a style='float:right' href='process.php?delete=".$row['id']."'>[delete]</a><a style='float:right' href='#'>[edit]</a><div style='clear:both'></div></div>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

### here is my online demo of above script

http://dzine.us/dev/mywall/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the code after the header() function is still executed.
This means that even when you want to redirect, the queries are still executed.

Try putting a die(); or exit(); line after your header('location: ...');

This will stop the rest of code to execute when you want to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The `header()` function changes the header location but doesn't redirect you till the rest of the code is executed. You can do this to make it redirect immediately:

```
header("Location: ...");
exit(0); //This should come just after header statement.
```

This will redirest to the other webpage as soon as you want, because the rest of the code will not be executed.